# Why is my Binary search stuck in an endless loop?

Tags: java, binary-search

I just had to pop in here to hopefully get a quick answer to my little problem. I'm trying to create a binary search method but ran into some problems. I created it iteratively, which my IDE(Intellij) apparently didn't like. It had me stuck in a endless loop of... well, you know the rest. Any suggestions?

Here is my simple, yet beautiful little snippet of code:

```
static int searchIt(int[] arr, int target){    
    int left = 0;                              
    int right = arr.length - 1;                
    while (left <= right){                     
        int mid = (right + left) / 2;          
        if(arr[mid] == target) {               
            return mid;                        
        } else if(target < arr[mid]){          
            right = mid-1;                     
        } else{                                
            left = mid -1;                     
        }                                      
    }                                          
    return -1;                                 
}
```

No errors, not in runtime or compile time, just endless nothingness...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

left value should be `mid + 1` since if the your middle your target value greater than your mid value then you need to search the element in second half of your array

```
static int searchIt(int[] arr, int target){    
    int left = 0;                              
    int right = arr.length - 1;                
    while (left <= right){                     
        int mid = (right + left) / 2;          
        if(arr[mid] == target) {               
            return mid;                        
        } else if(target < arr[mid]){          
            right = mid - 1;                     
        } else{                                
            left = mid + 1;                     
        }                                      
    }                                          
    return -1;                                 
}
```

Comment: Gosh darnit! smh... Thanks!